# array requested by name in variable doesn't works

Tags: php, arrays, variables, undefined

I have array in object and his name in variable. When i requests $object->$propertyWithArrayName its return array good but when i want to get value at index from this array it doesn't work.

Code:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar = array("A" => "a", "B" => "b");
    }
}

$test = new Foo();
$propertyName = "bar";
var_dump($test->$propertyName); // ok
var_dump($test->$propertyName["A"]); // doesn't work
```

Second var_dump raises `Warning: Illegal string offset 'A'` and `Notice: Undefined property: Foo::$b`.

Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$propertyName` is a string not an array, so to get the array using a string as it's name you need to disambiguate using curly braces `{ }`:

```
var_dump(
    $test->{$propertyName}["A"]
);
```